# What am I missing here? (Probability)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

An organization consists of 10 married couples. A lottery without replacement will decide a chairman and secretary. What's the probability that a married couple gets chosen?

My solution attempt:

There are 2 ways a couple can get the positions, so {(secretary, chairman),(chairman, secretary)}, but one is redundant so there is 1 combination. Now we need to determine how many ways of choosing 2 out of 2, that is $^{20}C_2$. Let our event be $A$, then $P(A) = \frac{1}{20C2}=\frac{1}{45}.$

The actual solution is $\frac{1}{19}$. I'm guessing that I have to multiply the ways of choosing 2 out of 2 by 10 to account for every couple? That would give the right solution, but I can't seem to convince myself of why that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $10$ couples so in your answer the numerator should be $10$. For denominator, $\binom{20}{2}=190\ne 45$. Thus the answer is $\frac{10}{190}=\frac{1}{19}$

Comment: thank you, this helped!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's correct. There are $^{20}C_2$ ways to choose two people to be secretary and chairman, if you don't care which is which, and there are $10$ ways to choose a married couple.

Another way to get to the same answer is as follows. First choose a chairman (it doesn't matter who gets chosen). Now there are $19$ people left, $1$ of whom is married to the chairman. We will choose one of these $19$ people to be the secretary, so the probability we choose the chairman's spouse is $1/19$.

Comment: That was clever, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we first choose chairman and then secretary.
There are 20 candidates.

Suppose a chairman is picked. $19$ people left. Only one person is the new chairman's husband/wife. Thus, with probability $1/19$ they get the position of secretary.

Comment: I appreciate the response!